# In Javascript, I'm using clearInterval() in a function/reset button - the timer resets, but keeps going

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a timer with setInterval():

```
var seconds = 0, minutes = 0;
var timer = document.querySelector("#timer");
var interval = null;
function beginTimer() {
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        timer.innerHTML = minutes + " Minute(s) " + seconds + "     Seconds";
        seconds++;
        if(seconds == 60) {
            minutes++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
        else if(minutes == 60) {
            return "Out of time!";          
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

I've set a button in HTML to reset it, but when I use it to clear the timer, it continues running. This is the function with the clearInterval() in it.

```
function beginGame() {
cards = shuffle(cards);
for (var n = 0; n < cards.length; n++) {
    allCards.innerHTML = "";
    [].forEach.call(cards, function(item) {
        allCards.appendChild(item);
    });
    cards[n].classList.remove("match", "open", "disable", "show");
}
    //resetting values
    moves = 0;
    counter.innerHTML = moves;
    star1.style.visibility = "visible";
    star2.style.visibility = "visible";
    star3.style.visibility = "visible";
    lemon.style.visibility = "hidden";

    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
    var timer = document.querySelector("#timer");
    timer.innerHTML = "0 Minute(s) 0 Seconds";
}
```

I've been researching this for a couple of days with no luck... could someone kindly help me understand how to stop the timer from continuing to run after reset is initialized? Thanks.

Comment: Inside of `beginTimer()`, remove the `var` in front of `interval`. That causes it to create a local variable in the function's scope, rather than referencing the one in the parent scope.

Answer (score 4):

Because you have `var interval` inside `beginTimer`, the `interval` variable inside `beginTimer` will always reference the *local* variable, which is distinct from the outer `interval` (which is never touched). Once `beginTimer` ends, the local `interval` variable will simply be garbage collected. Leave off the `var` to assign to the outer variable instead:

```
var interval = null;
function beginTimer() {
  interval = setInterval(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

`var interval`inside the `beginTimer()` is error.

```
var seconds = 0, minutes = 0;
var timer = document.querySelector("#timer");
var interval = null;
function beginTimer() {
   // var interval = setInterval(function(){
   interval = setInterval(function(){
    timer.innerHTML = minutes + " Minute(s) " + seconds + "     Seconds";
    seconds++;
    if(seconds == 60) {
        minutes++;
        seconds = 0;
    }
    else if(minutes == 60) {
        return "Out of time!";          
    }
   }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need also to reset the ongoing timer before starting a new one. Please try the following:

```
var interval;
function beginTimer() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function(){
...
```